# Enter Unspecified Number of Variables into Postgres Psycopg2 SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a postgresql database using psycogp2, and either exclude a variable number of rows or exclude none.

The code I have so far is:

```
def db_query(variables):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * '
                   'FROM database.table '
                   'WHERE id NOT IN (%s)', (variables,))
```

This does partially work. E.g. If I call:

```
db_query('593')
```

It works. The same for any other single value. However, I cannot seem to get it to work when I enter more than one variable, eg:

```
db_query('593, 595')
```

I get the error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "593, 595"
```

I'm not sure how to enter the query correctly or amend the SQL query. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The argument should be a list or a tuple. See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries (under "lists adaptation")

Answer (score 1):

Pass a tuple as it is adapted to a record:

```
query = """
    select *
    from database.table
    where id not in %s
"""
var1 = 593
argument = (var1,)
print(cursor.mogrify(query, (argument,)).decode('utf8'))
#cursor.execute(query, (argument,))
```

Output:

```
select *
from database.table
where id not in (593)
```

Comment: Thanks @clodoaldo Neto for the response. I'm not clear on how I can adapt this so I can pass in multiple variables?

Comment: @blountdj To pass multiple variables just do `argument = (var1, var2...)`